# Python for loop behavior

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, for-loop

Never run run accross this in python before, and I'm wondering why it happens and how I can avoid it. When I set `y = redundanciesArray` I want to make a copy of the array, change a value at some index, act on that change, and then reset `y` to be a fresh copy of the array. What happens is that on the first pass `redundanciesArray = [2,1,1,1,1]` and on the second pass it is `[2,2,1,1,1]`. It's sort of like `y` acting as a pointer to the `redundanciesArray`. I guess I'm not using arrays correctly or something, hopefully someone can shine a light on what I'm missing here.

```
redundanciesArray = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
probabilityArray =  [0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5]   
optimalProbability = 0
index = -1

for i in range(0, len(redundanciesArray)):
    y = redundanciesArray
    y[i] = y[i] + 1
    probability = calculateProbability(y, probabilityArray)
    //calcuateProbability returns a positive float between 0 and 1

    if(probability > optimalProbability):
        optimalProbability = probability
        index = i
```

Comment: You want to copy your array, for options see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-list-in-python

Comment: Yeah that works, I copied redundancies array instead of just setting it equal. What am I really doing then in this existing code? Making y a pointer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python uses names, which behave somewhat similar to references or pointers. So doing

```
y = redundanciesArray
```

will just make `y` *point to the same* object that `redundanciesArray` already pointed to. Both `y` and `redundanciesArray` are just names ("references to") the same object.

If you then do `y[i] = y[i] + 1`, it will modify position `i` in the object pointed to by both `y` and `redundanciesArray`.